# проблема с git-upload-pack

Tags: git, ssh, raspbian

Имеется raspberry pi работающая как веб-сервер, и компьютер на windows с которого я через ssh
пытаюсь скопировать git-репозиторий
`sudo git clone user@ip:C:/folder/project`
при попытке установить обычное ssh подключение всё работает
но тут выдаёт ошибку

```
Cloning into 'project'...
user@ip's password:
"git-upload-pack"   ७  譥
, ᯮ塞 ணࠬ   䠩.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: репа точно корректная? если на винде попробовать из какого-нибудь левого каталога склонировать git clone c:\filder\project

Comment: да на винде всё переносится нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверить не на чем, тем не менее попробуйте

1. изменить шелл по умолчанию для openssh

> powershell

> New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name
> DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType
> String -Force

2. Пробуйте клонировать (без двоеточия)

> git clone user@ip:/C/folder/project

Comment: Изменение шела помогло, а клонирование без двоеточия не работает даже после изменения